# What's the correct procedure for replacing an expired developer's certificate on an iPhone xCode project?

Tags: iphone, certificate

My iPhone developer certificate expired. I got a new one (developer_idendity.cer) but I'm not sure how to make my xcode project and my iPhone use it.

I keep getting the Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the applications Identifier 'com.example.foo' could not be found.

What's the procedure to follow when your developer certificate expires?

I created a new "developer_identity.cer" and put it on my keychain. Then I got a new "mycompany.mobileprovision". When I try to add this to xcode via the Organizer, I see the message:

```
A Valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain.
```

Any idea of what "signing identity" Xcode is looking for when I try to put in my update provisioning profile?

Comment: Normally you have just to re-download your original profile and it should work.

Comment: Well, it's not working! I added more information to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have your new provisioning profile selected within the Project Info Panel.  Click on your xcode project file on left under Groups & Files then click the Info Button beside the search box. When the info panel pops up, select the build tab then scroll down to the code signing field and select your new code signing identity there. It should work now. You might have to do it for your target file also. Basically repeat these same steps but click on the Target file under Targets in the Groups & Files pane. I hope this helps. There really is no wrong way to replace your expired certificates. Just add them to your key-chain and make sure you delete the old expired ones or there might be a conflict.